# How to Configure Spring Boot to Use an Alternate Properties File?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

How do I configure Spring Boot to use

```java
application-local.properties
```

instead of

```java
application.properties
```

working locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it looks like you want to have a `local` profile. In this case you could do the following, which would load `application-local.properties` if it is in your resources directory:

```kotlin
tasks.named<BootRun>("bootRun") {
    systemProperty(
        "spring.profiles.active",
        "local"
    )
}
```

Using this method, though, you have to keep ALL of your properties in BOTH `application.properties` and `application-local.properties`.

A better approach is to keep all of your defaults in `application.properties` and only keep your ***override*** properties in `application-local.properties`. AND not keep `application-local.properties` bundled with your application, which could lead to accidentally enabling the `local` profile in production.

To do this, put `application-local.properties` in your project root or in a subdirectory there and do this:

```kotlin
tasks.named<BootRun>("bootRun") {
    systemProperty(
        "spring.config.import",
        "file:application-local.properties"
    )
}
```

Details about how configuration files are loaded and the properties that can be set related to these can be found here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files

Comment: I believe I will simply use the power of GIT and ensure not to check in the application.properties (EVER) unless a real property has to be changed.  (Simply use STASH and POP).   In Spring Tool Suite you actually use TomCat and can sJet VM argument -Dspring.profiles.active=local.  I was hoping there was an easy answer.

Comment: Changing application.properties and simply not checking it in is error prone and likely to lead to inadvertently checking in the changed values. I high recommend against doing this. Anyhow, this setup above is easy and only has to be done one time.